Qiskit's SWAP Gate Doesn't Swap Qubits
I started learning Qiskit, and quantum computing in general, and recently the behaviour of the SWAP gate in Qiskit has been quite puzzling to me. I wrote the following circuit.
from itertools import product
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, transpile
from qiskit_aer import Aer

register_qubits = 2
register_bits = 2
zero_ket = [1, 0]
one_ket = [0, 1]
# Generate all possible combinations of zero_ket and one_ket
ket_combinations = list(product([zero_ket, one_ket], repeat=2))
first_qubit = 0
second_qubit = 1
shots = 100

for ket_combination in ket_combinations:
    quantum_register = QuantumRegister(register_qubits, "q")
    classical_register = ClassicalRegister(register_bits, "c")
    circuit = QuantumCircuit(quantum_register, classical_register)
    circuit.initialize(ket_combination[0], first_qubit)
    circuit.initialize(ket_combination[1], second_qubit)
    circuit.swap(quantum_register[first_qubit], quantum_register[second_qubit])
    circuit.measure(quantum_register, classical_register)

    simulator = Aer.get_backend("qasm_simulator")
    transpiled_circuit = transpile(circuit, simulator)
    result = simulator.run(transpiled_circuit, shots=shots).result()
    print(f"For the first qubit {ket_combination[0]} and the second qubit {ket_combination[1]} the SWAP result is: {result.get_counts(circuit)}")

When I run it, I get the following results:
For the first qubit [1, 0] and the second qubit [1, 0] the SWAP result is: {'00': 100}
For the first qubit [1, 0] and the second qubit [0, 1] the SWAP result is: {'01': 100}
For the first qubit [0, 1] and the second qubit [1, 0] the SWAP result is: {'10': 100}
For the first qubit [0, 1] and the second qubit [0, 1] the SWAP result is: {'11': 100}

I expected the qubits in the centre combinations (zero-ket and one-ket, and one-ket and zero-ket) to be swapped. This is what I calculated when I manually applied the matrix to those combinations (and logically this is what was supposed to happen). But it looks like the SWAP gate does nothing and works more like an identity matrix. What did I do wrong?

Qiskit uses little endian as default,
the first qubit [1, 0] and the second qubit [0, 1] => this is "10"
the first qubit [0, 1] and the second qubit [1, 0] => this is "01"
Your circuit has swapped above 2 states to "01" and "10" as expected.

Thanks a lot for explanation!
